# OSGeo4w installer fails: unable to extract /appa/qt5/bin/qt5webenginecored.pdb

Tags: installation, osgeo4w

I am trying to install OSGeo4w. I have plenty of RAM and disk space, running Server 2016 standard. Installation fails with the following log:

```
2019/07/08 09:13:30 Menu name: OSGeo4W
2019/07/08 09:13:30 net: Direct
2019/07/08 09:13:34 site: http://www.norbit.de/osgeo4w/
2019/07/08 09:15:50 Extracting from file://C:\Temp/http%3a%2f%2fwww.norbit.de%2fosgeo4w%2f/x86_64/release/qt5/qt5-libs-pdb-debug/qt5-libs-pdb-debug-5.9.2-1.tar.bz2
2019/07/08 09:17:48 Failed to output cygfile:///apps/Qt5/bin/Qt5WebEngineCored.pdb
2019/07/08 09:20:19 note: Installation Complete
2019/07/08 09:20:19 Ending OSGeo4W install
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

The answer below didn't resolve my issue. After installing Qt5 and running OSGeo4W setup again, I receive the same error. Additionally, after cloning the repo found at https://codereview.qt-project.org/admin/repos/qt/qtwebengine and running the OSGeo4W install again for the qt5webenginecoreed.pdb, error persists. Research shows that the debug file was no included in the 64-bit build, so I'm guessing that is the problem. Moreover, I don't know if this will affect the functionality at all either as my impetus behind the install was for python functionality with the gdal module.

**END UPDATE**

I'm having the same issue and ran across [this thread related to the qt sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674388/where-to-find-the-pdb-files-for-qts-dll). I don't know if it will help, but it does point in the direction of [Qt5 install](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/). If it works for me, I'll try to post back here. Really surprised your question has gone unanswered for this long.